# 'initWithNibName:bundle:' is unavailable LBTAFormController

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am new to swift, and i am working on a swift and objective-c mixed project. I got stuck , **if anyone could help, Thanks so much!**
I would like to use LBTAFormController(LBTATools).
In my project, I created FormViewController.swift and FormViewController.xib.
I want to pushViewController to FormViewController.swift

```
FormViewController * loginForm = [[FormViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginFormViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginForm animated:YES];
```

in FormViewController.swift, I set up like this:

```
import UIKit
import LBTATools

class FormViewController: LBTAFormController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

However, I always got error

> 'initWithNibName:bundle:' is unavailable